# Access nested json objects in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to access a nested `JSON` object, but I am getting `Cannot read property 'module' of undefined`.

Here is the `JSON` file.

```
{
  "server": {
    "module": {
      "InPluginPath": "/usr/home/nah/Website/server/httpModule.js"
    }
  }
}
```

Then when I try to access the `JSON` object after reading the file with `fs.readFile()`, I get the `Cannot read property 'module' of undefined`, error. Below is the line that causes the error.

```
console.log(config.server.module.InPluginPath);
```

Comment: Please show the specific code you use with `fs.readFile()`.  Do you know that `require()` will load and parse a .json file for you automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `JSON.parse()` the resulting *string* from `fs.readFile()`. For example:

```
fs.readFile('/tmp/foo.json', { encoding: 'utf8' }, function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  try {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log('Error parsing json');
    return;
  }
  console.log(data.server.module.InPluginPath);
});
```

Comment: Or, you could load it as a module with `require()` and it will get parsed automatically.

Comment: @jfriend00 Except `require()` will cache the result, just like modules, and save it in memory. This is not desirable in all cases. Additionally the OP had already mentioned using `fs.readFile()`, so I thought it was more fitting.

Comment: Its not a criticism, but a suggestion for something you could add to your answer to make it more complete.

Comment: Your `console.log()` statement isn't using the parsed results.  Maybe want to correct that.